# Collector editing all messages Discord.JS v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

If I use two or more commands with buttons in sequence and I click any of the buttons in any message, all messages are edited. I would like to know if there is a way to fix this error.

`const filter = i => i.isButton() && (i.customId === "prev" || i.customId === "next" || i.customId === "source") && (i.user.id === message.author.id)`

Comment: How do you use this `filter` in your collector?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating the collector on the channel, and don't have unique custom ids. Create the collector on the message, or if the message isn't available yet, make a unique custom id (example: add the interaction id to the custom id)

```js
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter })
```

Or if you want to use a unique custom id:

```js
.setCustomId(`prev${interaction.id}`) // for example
// ...
const filter = i => i.isButton() &&
  (i.customId === `prev${interaction.id}` ||
  i.customId === `next${interaction.id}` ||
  i.customId === `source${interaction.id}`) &&
  (i.user.id === message.author.id) // Note: interaction.id is not the same as i.id
```